# Your preferred Wordpress Dev/Migration Process

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I was briefly doing some Wordpress development a number of years ago. As I remember - it was a total pain to develop locally then migrate to a live webserver. Just wondering what some folks real-world 2016 ways of handling this are.

Comment: Use Backup Buddy. Complete automation or semi automation. Very simple and intuitive. I've probably migrated 100+ sites using it. https://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/

Answer (score 0):

I moved a wordress install earlier today from one server to another, I read up on it at https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress and I don´t think that there is that much else to do. You need to change the config file and move the database (unless it´s something that can be installed in a fresh install of wordpress). Then either use GIT or FTP to get the files in place. Didn´t feel like that big of a pain.